# Must choose GRUB in boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

first I'm sorry for bad typing because I'm not native to this language. 
I've been recently install ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop (Lenovo ideapad 1 - UEFI) but when installation is over laptop doesn't boot to Ubuntu it's just keep restarting until I choose GRUB from boot menu.
I tried to set GRUB as first option to boot but when I rebooting nothing changes and laptop still restarting until choose GRUB from boot menu.

Comment: What do you see when it reboots? What does it mean “I choose Grub from boot menu”? What do you mean by that? Why do you see on this “boot menu”?

Comment: problem is I see nothing just a prompt "Reset system" then system keep rebooting until  I press f12 and choose GRUB from boot menu